# How to add same code at multiple places in OCMOD OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, ocmod

I want to place the code after the `$order_product_id = $this->db->getLastId()` which occur 2 times in `order.php` file. I want to place the code in both places. The OCMOD is placing the code as instructed but it is also adding the code third time and placing it in random place.

```
<file path="catalog/model/checkout/order.php">
    <operation>
        <search trim="true" index="0">
            <![CDATA[
             $order_product_id = $this->db->getLastId();
             ]]>
        </search>
        <add position="after">
            <![CDATA[
                if($product['variation_detail_id']){
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `oc_order_variation`( `order_id`, `order_product_id`, `product_variation_detail_id`) VALUES (".(int)$order_id.",".(int)$order_product_id.",".(int)$product['variation_detail_id'].")");
        }
            ]]>
        </add>
    </operation>

</file>
```

I have also tried using offset but it neglect the first occurrence and place the code in the second occurrence only.
Is there a way to add the code in both places?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like as

"index=0,1,2"

I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here, You have not need to add  `index="0"`for that. please try following code.

```
<file path="catalog/model/checkout/order.php">
    <operation>
        <search trim="true">
            <![CDATA[
             $order_product_id = $this->db->getLastId();
             ]]>
        </search>
        <add position="after">
            <![CDATA[
                if($product['variation_detail_id']){
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `oc_order_variation`( `order_id`, `order_product_id`, `product_variation_detail_id`) VALUES (".(int)$order_id.",".(int)$order_product_id.",".(int)$product['variation_detail_id'].")");
        }
            ]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

You can find official OCMOD documentation [Here](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System)